# Laravel/Eloquent normalize relations for JSON response?

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

(Edited to add a better example with multiple characters with the same book and author)

Using Laravel 8, but this must be a generic enough problem I just don't know the name for or can't find. I've tried "normalizing eloquent JSON response" ad nauseum and nothing seems to be this specific issue.

I have some basic relations defined in Laravel, but I want to separate them out for a JSON response.

e.g.

Character belongsTo Book

Book belongsTo Author

So (ignore any syntax issues, it's quickly typed pseudo code)

```php
$characters = Character::with('book', 'book.author')->get();
$characters->toJson();
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "book_id": 1,
        "name": "Some character",
        "book": [{
           "id": 1,
           "author_id": 1,
           "name": "Some book",
           "author": [{
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Some author"
           }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "book_id": 1,
        "name": "A second character",
        "book": [{
           "id": 1,
           "author_id": 1,
           "name": "Some book",
           "author": [{
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Some author"
           }]
        }]
    }
]
```

But what I really want is this so I can feed it into a front end (React) simple ORM, but unnested and deduplicated (since the originally nested response could have the same book entry for multiple characters for example).

```json
{
   "characters": [{
      "id": 1,
      "book_id": 1,
      "name": "Some character"
   }, {
      "id": 2,
      "book_id": 1,
      "name": "A second character"
   }],
   "books": [{
      "id": 1,
      "author_id": 1,
      "name": "Some book"
   }],
   "authors": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Some author"
   }],
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple `Character` then how you separte those books and authors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Each resource (Character, Book, Author) would be an array of all its items and as long as they have the relevant foreign key IDs I can look them up

Comment: Try something like, `$characters = Character::with('book.author')->get(); $result = ["characters" => $characters->makeHidden('book'),
"books" => $characters->books->makeHidden('author'),
"authors" => $characters->books->$authors
];
return (json_encode($result));`

Comment: Or try this :
`$characters = Character::get();
$books = Book::whereIn('id', $characters->pluck('book_id')->toArray())->get();
$authors = Author::whereIn('id', $books->pluck('author_id')->toArray())->get();

json_encode([
    "characters" => $characters,
    "books" => ,
    "authors" => $characters->books->$authors
])`